# fltk cannot find -lXcursor in codeblocks

Tags: c++

I installed fltk on my codeblocks IDE yesternight and it works fine, i was able to run a "Hello world" program on it but then i deleted the previous project and created a new one but i'm getting this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXcursor
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXfixes
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))
3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))
```

I'm using the linux OS with GNU GCC compiler

Comment: Looks like you're missing those two libraries. You'll have to install them, and presumably their corresponding development headers, before this will compile. It's not clear why they're being included, but I'm not familiar with how Codeblocks sets up projects. GCC won't do this by default. The package dependencies vary considerably according to your Linux distribution.

Comment: @tadman i ran this same program some hours ago and it works. i didn't tampered the IDE settings and all i did was to create a new project and this happen.

Comment: "i ran this same program some hours ago and it works" Sorry, we cannot debug supernatural phenomena.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev
```

Installing the library has solved the problem for me.